# Error : Authorization has been denied for this request

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have created web api method to insert some data. It works fine anonymously. But when I decorate the method with  [Authorize] , I recieve message like "Message": "Authorization has been denied for this request." jwt bearer token was entered with the request.I run the function using Postman. Should I add any class to validate the bearer token?

```
    [Authorize]
    [Route("customer")]
    public String customer(APICustomer APICustomer1)
    {
        try
        {
           
           insert_Customer(APICustomer1.custid, APICustomer1.custname, APICustomer1.status);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            
        }
       
        return "1";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Authentication is the process of validating user credentials and authorization is the process of checking privileges for a user to access specific modules in an application.
Please read the article for more detailed information: [Authentication And Authorization In ASP.NET Core Web API With JSON Web Tokens](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/authentication-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core-web-api-with-json-web-tokens/)